# Trying to retrieve the profile picture

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm trying to make an app where the registered user has to upload a profile pic.
After that, when the user logs in along with his other credentials the image of the user should also get displayed.

Until now the image is getting uploaded on the server.
I don't know how to make the image available when the user logins.

Comment: what have you tried anything so far? are you saving the location of the profile pics in a database along with the user ids?

Comment: the image on server in a folder named 'pictures' and the user details are stored in the mysql table . both are on same server

Answer (score 0):

Save the image name to the user table.  When the user logs in, you are already looking up data on them - simply pull that image name in, as well.  Voila.

Answer (score 0):

When you register the user credentials will be saved in database and profilePic will be saved in server with link to the picture must be saved in database, then when user login, you have to make some authentication api calls, through that you will get output in `json` or `xml` format based upon your need.

In Json:

```
    {
    "success": "1",
    "user_details": {
    "name": "xxxx",
    "email": "xxxx@gmail.com",
    "prof_image": "http://server_location/xxx.png"
    }
    }
```